# How to use a data model attribute as html id attribute

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a User model with `name` and `email` attributes.
I would like to use a user's name as html id attribute for a table row.
Requiring `id` a string and being `name` a string, I am undecided whether the following notation is correct:

```
<tr id=<%= user.name %>>
```

or am I expected to explicitly use double quotation marks after the html id attribute, so for instance use instead one of the following solutions:

```
<tr id="<%= user.name %>">
<tr id="#{<%= user.name %>}">
```

I am pretty sure that `<tr id="<%= user.name %>">` would produce `id="'Dave'"`, instead of `id="Dave"` (quotation inside quotation), while I am not sure that the interpolation makes any sense at all. The second solution would work if I chose `user.id` instead of `user.name`.

Comment: Do you have a unique validation on user `name`s? otherwise you can't  use `name` as `id`s(You can of course use, but there will be multiple nodes with the same id). Better use the record id

Comment: Yes, I added an index in Postgresql to the 'name' column and a unique constraint.

Comment: You keep talking about id selectors, but I don't see any use of a CSS selector here. Did you mean id attributes?

Comment: You are right @BoltClock, I meant html id attribute. I made the necessary corrections to title and post content. Thanks for reporting the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr id="<%= user.name %>">
```

is the correct construction. It is better to use the record id as has already been suggested but, hey, it's your code. You will need to make sure that the name field doesn't contain spaces or other characters not allowed in id attributes.

In my Rails apps, I prefix all my id attributes as follows to ensure that they are absolutely unique on any page:

```
<tr id="user_<%= user.id %>">
```